# pidstat: difference between task and process?

Tags: linux, kernel, process, performance-monitoring

The [`pidstat` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pidstat.1.html) has options relating to tasks and others relating to processes (e.g. `-C` and `-G`). What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux *processes* are one more *tasks* that share a *thread group ID*.

Processes are an executing program. Tasks are what Linux schedules, everything is a task. Threads are another name for a schedulable unit of execution, sometimes multiple lightweight threads per process. Although, Linux is more the other way, that processes are "heavyweight" threads.

[Task status documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/accounting/taskstats.html) describes them as:

> “pid”, “tid” and “task” are used interchangeably and refer to the
>   standard Linux task defined by struct task_struct. per-pid stats are
>   the same as per-task stats.
>
> “tgid”, “process” and “thread group” are used interchangeably and
>   refer to the tasks that share an mm_struct i.e. the traditional Unix
>   process.

What many think of as the UNIX pid is technically the tgid. And there is a pid field in task_struct that could be considered a task ID.

pidstat has the ability to query details. A good UI uses terms the user expects, in this case processes and threads. pidstat -p will report as PID, but pidstat -p -t will report as TGID, and all threads with TID. Neat trick for showing how one process can use more than 100% of a CPU.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled why TGID is set only for the thread group leader and is 0 for all the threads. Based on your description (and https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/accounting/taskstats.html) I thought it would be the same number for all the threads, meaning that they all belong to the same "process".